# Kohana 3.2 не работает get_user().

Tags: php, kohana

Всем привет. Не понимаю где ошибка, при проверке get_user() возвращает false. Где я делаю не правильно?

```
public function action_index()
{ 
    $content=View::factory('admin/info_view');
    $content->bind('user', $user);
    $this->template->content = $content;

    $auth = Auth::instance();
    $user = $auth->get_user();

    if (!$user)
    {
        Request::current()->redirect('admin/login');
    }
}

public function action_login()
{
    $this->template->content = View::factory('admin/login_view')
        ->bind('message', $message);

    if (HTTP_Request::POST === $this->request->method()) 
    {
        $remember = array_key_exists('remember', $this->request->post()) ? (bool) $this->request->post('remember') : FALSE;
        $login=$this->request->post('username');
        $pass=$this->request->post('password');
        $auth = Auth::instance();
        $auth->login($login, $pass, $remember);

        if ($auth) 
        {
            Request::current()->redirect('admin/index');
        } 
        else
        {
            $message = 'Login failed';
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Вернет значение если только пользователь залогинился. Видимо вы не смогли зайти. Проверьте сессию отладками

Comment: $auth->login($login, $pass, $remember);

     if ($auth) 
     {
            Request::current()->redirect('admin/index');
     }else...
    

----------
     if ($auth->login($login, $pass, $remember)) 
     {
            Request::current()->redirect('admin/index');
     }else...

Comment: спасибо. Я невнимателен.
Все равно не работает.

Comment: Где Вы храните пользователей? Auth, который поставляется с Kohana 3.2 работает только с файловым драйвером. Покажите config.

Comment: В таблице users.

<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

return array(

 'driver'       => 'orm',
 'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
 'hash_key'     => 'moment',
 'lifetime'     => 1209600,
 'session_type' => Session::$default,
 'session_key'  => 'auth_user'
);

Comment: Вы создали таблицу ролей и привязали своему пользователю роль login
?

Comment: задавал admin, а если задать в ролях login то все работает. Ну это уже лучше, спасибо. Но почему с admin не работает?

Comment: потому что внутри класса жестко прописанно, что у пользователя должна быть роль login. А вообще связь один ко многим, т.е. пользователю надо назначить роли и admin, и login.

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло.

Comment: @activist, всё работает нормально и с ОРМ! Не нужно наговаривать!